# No Wifi Options in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: wireless, 22.04, broadcom, adapter

I've installed Ubuntu 22.04 on HP laptop and the wifi option is no gone from the settings, and not working anymore.

I know this question was asked many times before, but I've been searching and trying for hours now and I couldn't find any answer that works for me.
I've tried solutions provided by @chili555 and @Luis Alvarado and installed both `bcmwl-kernel-source` and `firmware-b43-installer` with no luck.

Here is the results from the wireless-info.txt

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 29 Sep 2022 18:14 EET +0200

Booted last: 29 Sep 2022 00:00 EET +0200

Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.15.0-48-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 26 13:26:29 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: NAMI
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:804a]

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [103c:80cc]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. Root Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:216d Broadcom Corp. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. Root Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0000:3813  mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled
Platform is in Setup Mode

##### lsmod #############################

mac80211             1159168  0
cfg80211              958464  1 mac80211
compat                 16384  2 mac80211,cfg80211
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
ssb                    86016  0
hp_wmi                 20480  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
platform_profile       16384  1 hp_wmi
wmi_bmof               16384  0
bcma                   73728  0
wmi                    32768  2 hp_wmi,wmi_bmof

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.1.4/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp3s0
       valid_lft 85632sec preferred_lft 85632sec
    inet6 fdd8:2918:fa21:6d00:ecfe:4d5a:a7d7:b66/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 7112sec preferred_lft 3512sec
    inet6 fdd8:2918:fa21:6d00:3f48:4feb:d179:605/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 7112sec preferred_lft 3512sec
    inet6 fe80::a8f0:2ba0:ec58:d2d6/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp3s0 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp3s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.4 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search home

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root         859       1  0 18:01 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.15.0-48-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.5/0000:03:00.0/net/enp3s0
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:03:00.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp3s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       bd5fd4bd-90a2-3517-9b7f-d4d41f7fa458
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.4/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          home
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        domain_name = home
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        expiry = 1664553685
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        ip_address = 192.168.1.4
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fdd8:2918:fa21:6d00:ecfe:4d5a:a7d7:b66/64
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         fdd8:2918:fa21:6d00:3f48:4feb:d179:605/64
IP6.ADDRESS[3]:                         fe80::a8f0:2ba0:ec58:d2d6/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fdd8:2918:fa21:6d00::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.DNS[1]:                             fe80::1
DHCP6.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp6_name_servers = fe80::1
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/1
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   bd5fd4bd-90a2-3517-9b7f-d4d41f7fa458 | Wired connection 1

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com./

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-31-mac-addr-change]
match-device=driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

'iw' is not installed (package "iw").

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp3s0    no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.15.0-48-generic/updates/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
depends:        cfg80211,compat,libarc4
retpoline:      Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       5.15.0-48-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.15.0-48-generic/updates/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
depends:        compat
retpoline:      Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       5.15.0-48-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

[ssb]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.15.0-48-generic/kernel/drivers/ssb/ssb.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Sonics Silicon Backplane driver
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ssb
vermagic:       5.15.0-48-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[bcma]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.15.0-48-generic/kernel/drivers/bcma/bcma.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Broadcom's specific AMBA driver
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           bcma
vermagic:       5.15.0-48-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

##### module parameters #################

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[  192.271799] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:9904:0e80336f
[  193.379265] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_get_response_rate
[  193.379284] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_get_response_rate (err -22)
[  193.379610] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_free_hw
[  193.379616] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_free_hw (err -22)
[  193.379678] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_register_hw
[  193.379683] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_register_hw (err -22)
[  193.379787] b43: disagrees about version of symbol __ieee80211_get_radio_led_name
[  193.379794] b43: Unknown symbol __ieee80211_get_radio_led_name (err -22)
[  193.379807] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_generic_frame_duration
[  193.379812] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_generic_frame_duration (err -22)
[  193.379824] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_wake_queue
[  193.379829] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_wake_queue (err -22)
[  193.379887] b43: disagrees about version of symbol __ieee80211_get_tx_led_name
[  193.379892] b43: Unknown symbol __ieee80211_get_tx_led_name (err -22)
[  193.380221] b43: disagrees about version of symbol __ieee80211_get_rx_led_name
[  193.380227] b43: Unknown symbol __ieee80211_get_rx_led_name (err -22)
[  193.380404] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_queue_delayed_work
[  193.380409] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_queue_delayed_work (err -22)
[  193.380432] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_ctstoself_get
[  193.380436] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_ctstoself_get (err -22)
[  193.380612] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_wake_queues
[  193.380619] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_wake_queues (err -22)
[  193.380641] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_free_txskb
[  193.380646] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_free_txskb (err -22)
[  193.380726] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_alloc_hw_nm
[  193.380731] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_alloc_hw_nm (err -22)
[  193.380789] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_tx_status
[  193.380794] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_tx_status (err -22)
[  193.380804] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_stop_queue
[  193.380809] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_stop_queue (err -22)
[  193.380858] b43: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_rfkill_set_hw_state_reason
[  193.380863] b43: Unknown symbol wiphy_rfkill_set_hw_state_reason (err -22)
[  193.380877] b43: disagrees about version of symbol __ieee80211_get_assoc_led_name
[  193.380882] b43: Unknown symbol __ieee80211_get_assoc_led_name (err -22)
[  193.380900] b43: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_rfkill_start_polling
[  193.380905] b43: Unknown symbol wiphy_rfkill_start_polling (err -22)
[  193.381003] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_unregister_hw
[  193.381008] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_unregister_hw (err -22)
[  193.381032] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_beacon_get_tim
[  193.381036] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_beacon_get_tim (err -22)
[  193.381054] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_channel_to_freq_khz
[  193.381059] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_channel_to_freq_khz (err -22)
[  193.381083] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_rts_get
[  193.381087] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_rts_get (err -22)
[  193.381156] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_queue_work
[  193.381162] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_queue_work (err -22)
[  193.381268] b43: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_rx_napi
[  193.381273] b43: Unknown symbol ieee80211_rx_napi (err -22)

########## wireless info END ############
```

I've followed the answer given at insatlling broadcam driver below with no luck.
[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @waltinator I've used the answer in this question to get the informations of the wifi but as I'm not an expert I couldn't figure out what was the problem. I want to post the results from the wireless info file but don't know how.

Comment: @waltinator I've edited the question with the results of the wireless-file.txt

Comment: Please add output of `dkms status` to your question. It looks like you didn't install `bcmwl-kernel-source`. What does `sudo modprobe wl` output?

Comment: Uninstall whatever backports you installed and reboot

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks for your answers, I did a clean install of Ubuntu and it's working fine now.

Comment: @Jeremy31 Thanks for your answer, I did a clean install of Ubuntu and it's working fine now.